# Setting id on an active resource object

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeresource

We have to restore a deleted record using active resource with the same id it had before deletion.

```
a = ActiveResourceModel.new

a.new? # true

a = ActiveResourceModel.new

a.id = 1234

a.new? # false
```

If the active resource object has id attribute set, it is always considered as a saved object and it always tries to update the record. We had to create a custom post action to set the id to the previous value. Is there any other way of doing this?

Answer (score 1):

the `ActiveResource::Base` source shows this:

```
def new?
  id.nil?
end
```

So you have to override the `new?` method, or to call the private method `create` directly

```
class YourModel < ActiveResource::Base

  def restore
    create
  end

  # or
  def new?
    @some_custom_flag_variable ? true : id.nil?
  end

end
```

be prepared to handle errrors if the id is already taken, though (who knows ?)